# How can I sort this table from largest number to smallest?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

Trying to sort the following table by the "rankscore" td from largest number to smallest.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<h4>Current Rank</h4>
<table id="rank">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="namecell">Joe:</td>
            <td class="rankscore">7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="namecell">Jim:</td>
            <td class="rankscore">13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="namecell">Megan:</td>
            <td class="rankscore">936</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="namecell">Greg:</td>
            <td class="rankscore">13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="namecell">Will:</td>
            <td class="rankscore">20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="namecell">Paul:</td>
            <td class="rankscore">15</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="namecell">Tammy:</td>
            <td class="rankscore">133</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="namecell">Chari:</td>
            <td class="rankscore">123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="namecell">Ed:</td>
            <td class="rankscore">6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="namecell">Hank:</td>
            <td class="rankscore">13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="namecell">Bill:</td>
            <td class="rankscore">13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="namecell">Al:</td>
            <td class="rankscore">21</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="namecell">Stacy:</td>
            <td class="rankscore">13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="namecell">Mack:</td>
            <td class="rankscore">13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="namecell">Ira:</td>
            <td class="rankscore">13</td>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>

<script>
function sortTable(table, order) {
    var asc   = order === 'asc',
        tbody = table.find('tbody');

    tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a, b) {
        if (asc) {
            return $('td.rankscore', a).text().localeCompare($('td.rankscore', b).text());
        } else {
            return $('td.rankscore', b).text().localeCompare($('td.rankscore', a).text());
        }
    }).appendTo(tbody);
}

sortTable($('#rank'), 'desc');
</script>

</html>
```

Current code results in the following table:

```
Megan:  936
Joe:    7
Ed:     6
Al:     21
Will:   20
Paul:   15
Tammy:  133
Hank:   13
Jim:    13
Greg:   13
Bill:   13
Ira:    13
Stacy:  13
Mack:   13
Chari:  123
```

The function seems to just look at the first digit when sorting rather than taking all digits into account.

I didn't write this sorting function and it's difficult for me to figure out what exactly it's doing. I looked up a page explaining localCompare but it didn't really help much.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the scores sorted by string order, not numerical order. You need to convert the text to numbers, then compare with `<`, `>`, `<=`, etc., as appropriate.

You need something like this:

```
    const aNum = parseInt($('td.rankscore', a).text());
    const bNum = parseInt($('td.rankscore', a).text());

    if (asc) {
        return (aNum === bNum ? 0 : (aNum < bNum ? -1 : 1);
    } else {
        return (aNum === bNum ? 0 : (aNum > bNum ? -1 : 1);
    }
```

I haven't tested this, I might have the < and > around backward, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: Hm...not getting this to work. I'm getting all kinds of wacky results using your code.